# Assign axes to the chart in xlwings

Tags: python, excel, charts, xlwings

By using the script below I can generate the chart but it assigns columns to abscissa. How can I assign the rows to it, i.e. x,y,z as abscissa and A,B,C as ordinates.

[image]

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book(r"tests.xlsx")
ws = wb.sheets['Sheet1']

# adding a plot
cp = (10, 10)
ch = ws.charts.add(top=ws.range(cp).top, left=ws.range(cp).left, width=800, height=300)
ch.chart_type = 'line_markers'
ch.set_source_data(ws.range('A1:D3'))
# putting the chart title
ch.api[1].SetElement(2)
ch.api[1].ChartTitle.Text = 'Test'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.api` and [`Chart.PlotBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.plotby)

```
ch.api[0].Chart.PlotBy = 2
```

where `2` [corresponds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlrowcol) to the constant `xlColumns`.

Output:

[image]